# Scroll Magic fade in up

Tags: jquery, animation, scrollmagic

I have a pretty simple set up

```
<section class="section">
    <p>Dummy section</p>
</section>
<section id="inside" class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3>Some title</h3>
                <br><br><br>
                <p class="section-subtitle">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I put a dummy section in there so I can trigger the effect.  Each section is `100vh`.

Essentially, I am trying to achieve two things.  Firstly, as you scroll down, I want the `section-subtitle` to fade in.  So maybe start it at about 0.2 opacity, and make it stronger as you scroll down.

The other thing I am after is to place this text about 50px below its natural position.  As you scroll down, I need it to slide up back into its position.

At the moment, I have the following

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

var fadein_tween = TweenMax.to('.section-subtitle', 1, { y:-300 , opacity:0 , ease:Power1.easeInOut  });

var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: "#inside",
  duration: jQuery(window).height()
})  .setTween(fadein_tween)
.addTo(controller);
```

As you can see from this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/44/) it is not quite correct.  At the moment, it is fading out, not in.  Additionally, it is going past its normal position, into the other section.

Is there any way to achieve what I am after?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To achieve opacity and transition you want, you can use fromTo in GSAP - this sets the elements attributes before animating them.

In this case I've set the yPercent to 100 (translateY:100%) and opacity to 0.2, then animated them to 0 and 1 respectively.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxtLepLb/) demonstrating.

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

var fadein_tween = TweenMax
.fromTo('.section-subtitle', 1, { yPercent:100 , opacity:0.2 }, { yPercent:0 , opacity:1 , ease:Power1.easeInOut  });

var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: "#inside",
  trigerHook:"onEnter",
  duration: "50%"
})  
.setTween(fadein_tween)
.addTo(controller);
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I've been looking for.